# Find conda env folder in mac

Tags: environment, anaconda3

I cannot find `envs` folder on anaconda3 when navigating through mac finder.

On bash, if I run

```
conda env list
```

I can see my environment are located at

```
base   */opt/anconda3
myenv   /opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv
```

However, when navigating through Mac Finder, I can only see the following folder

```
user/anaconda3/
```

Inside I cannot see the `envs` folder

I have isntalled conda version

```
conda 4.10.1
```

I tried using on finder the "Go to folder" option, and entering

```
user/opt
```

But it did not work.

Comment: did you try `/opt/anaconda3` ?

Comment: @S.Chauhan write it as an answer, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `/opt/anaconda3` instead.

Comment: Note to reviewers: this is the answer (see comments on the question). It might not be an amazing answer, but it clearly solved the problem at hand so should not be deleted. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29351796).

Comment: Note to S.Chauhan - you should edit your answer to explain why this works.

Comment: Note to @S.Chuhan : it worked because /opt/ is a hidden file on mac

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.